# How do you include static html files in your templates?

Tags: html, templates, static, haml, precompile

I want to create my first statice html template to sell it on theme forest or somewhere else. But how can I create my templates without redudant html code, e.g. header or footer? In PHP you can use the include function, but this is a server side include and frames are the wrong way.

How do the professionals manage their static html templates? Do they use HAML to precompile the html code? Or do they really manage every single html file manually?

Thanks,
rjgamer

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what framework you are using. If you are on ruby you will likely use a layout file with a header and footer and a `yield` call where you want the specific content to appear. In rails this is done automatically for you by naming convention. Other frameworks may do it differently.